# Marking items in a listview then looping through them to grab checked items properties

Tags: listview, for-loop, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have this code here:

```
$.clientList.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e){
    var item = e.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
    var items = e.section.getItems();

    if (item.properties.accessoryType == Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE) {
        item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_CHECKMARK;
    }
    else {
        item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE;
    }
    e.section.updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, item); 

 });
```

which allows me to check and uncheck items in my listview. I want to, after the user is done checking items from this listview. Grab the values of item.properties.clientname and item.properties.clientid from the listview.

How do I do this? I want to loop through this listview and only grab the selected items of the listview.

Thanks,
Kenny

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/163878/loop-through-listview-to-grab-items-with-certain-properties#comment-206400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function convertListToArrayOfClients(list) {
    var sections = list.sections,
        retVal = [];
    for(var i = 0, iL = sections.length; i < iL; i++) {
        var section = sections[i],
            items = section.items;
        for(var j = 0, jL = items.length; j < jL; j++) {
            var item = items[j];
            retVal.push({
                clientid: item.properties.clientid,
                clientname: item.properties.clientname,
                checked: item.properties.accessoryType == Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_CHECKMARK
            });
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
var arr = convertListToArrayOfClients($.clientList);
```